# JFreeChart: Совмещение на одном графике гистограммы и линии

Tags: java, диаграммы, jfree

Как нарисовать на одном графике в java (я использую JFreeChart) гистограмму и линию. Я пытаюсь нарисовать гистограмму по точкам линией, но получается не очень.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Незаметная с первого взгляда синяя линия у в самом низу графика это построенная мною "гистограмма"

```
public class PDFChart {
public void Construct
        (double[] data, int NumberOfBins, double standardDeviation, double mean, float plotLimitLeft, float plotLimitRight) {
    Arrays.sort(data);
    double first_part= standardDeviation * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI);
    double second_part= 2 * standardDeviation * standardDeviation;
    XYSeries series0 = new XYSeries("Theoretical Probability density function");
    for(float i = plotLimitLeft; i < plotLimitRight; i+=0.25){
        series0.add(i, Math.exp(-(Math.pow(i - mean,2)) / second_part) / first_part );
    }
    XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series0);

    //Подготавливаем нормированную гистограмму
    DataProcessing ds = new DataProcessing();
    double LengthOfBin = ds.LengthOfBin(data,NumberOfBins);
    XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Empirical normalized histogram");
    int n;
    double [] BoundsOfBins = new double[NumberOfBins+1];
    // Задаём границы бинов в массив
    for (int i = 0; i<BoundsOfBins.length; i++)
        BoundsOfBins[i]=data[0]+i*LengthOfBin;
    int[] PointsInBin = new int[NumberOfBins];
    //Считаем, сколько на каждый бин приходится точек
    for (n=0;n<NumberOfBins; n++)
        for (double aData : data) {
            if (BoundsOfBins[n] >= aData & aData <= BoundsOfBins[n + 1])
                PointsInBin[n]++;

        }
    n=0;
    //Добавляем в серию точки, описывающие контур гистограммы
    for (float i = plotLimitLeft;i<plotLimitRight;i+=0.01){
        if (n<NumberOfBins)
            if (i>=BoundsOfBins[n]) {
                n++;
            }
        series2.add(i, n>PointsInBin.length?(double) PointsInBin[n]/data.length/LengthOfBin:0);
    }

    ((XYSeriesCollection) xyDataset).addSeries(series2);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart
            ("PDF", "Argument x", "Probability n",
                    xyDataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    true, true, true);
    JFrame frame =
            new JFrame("PDF Chart");
    // Помещаем график на фрейм
    frame.getContentPane()
            .add(new ChartPanel(chart));
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Задумывалось сопоставление на одном графике гистограммы и линии для другой математической функции.